# Can you use Consul instead of Zookeeper for Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, consul

I am looking at using Kafka but the documentation states that I need to set up Zookeeper. I already have a service discovery set up, I am using Consul. I don't want to have to look after Zookeeper as well.

Can you use Consul instead of Zookeeper to run Kafka? If so is there any documentation on how to do this anywhere?

Comment: You can still register your brokers as a Consul service for DNS service discovery, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Kafka currently supports only Apache Zookeeper. It doesn't have any out of the box support for Consul.

Answer (score 4):

This long-standing [Kafka issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1793) tracks adding Zookeeper alternatives. It may never happen, so in the meantime, there's the option of running a Zookeeper proxy like [zetcd](https://coreos.com/blog/introducing-zetcd) or [parkeeper](https://github.com/glerchundi/parkeeper) in front of etcd or Consul.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka only uses Zookeeper for broker and topic discovery.  Short of adding Consul support to the code base yourself, there is no other alternatives.

Comment: ... And leader election